# Multiple fonts on a single line of an eps file?

Tags: eps

I'm trying to manipulate and modify a large number of eps files output by a web service. I have the code in python to interface with the server, and to edit the images to within about 99% of where I want them.

My issue deals with trying to display special characters. I've tried outputting the desired unicode character, Ψ, directly into the eps file, but this is displayed as different characters in both Preview for Mac and Adobe Illustrator. From some googling, it seems like eps doesn't accept unicode characters. Fair enough...

My current solution is to try to change the font in the eps files. This works when I want to display the Ψ as a single character. I just switch the font, and then switch back. As below:

```
    /Symbol findfont 10.5 scalefont setfont
    -9.1 36.1557 moveto (Y) show
    /Helvetica-Bold findfont 10.5 scalefont setfont
```

Where I'm having a problem is when I want to display a title on each image. The title would include a mix of `Helvetica-Light` and `Symbol` fonts, I would want it to display as `ABC1-Ψ123`. I can't figure out how to switch the font of a single character within a larger block of text. Currently the eps files are written as shown:

```
    /Helvetica-Light findfont 12 scalefont setfont
    -43.093 304.224 moveto (ABC1-Y123) show
```

I'd appreciate any help.